# How to assign NSMutableDictionary setObject value to become indexPath.section value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsdictionary

I have NSMutableDictionary and return result as below:-

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        distinctNames = [_aryClippedCategoryList valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.category_id"];
        for (NSString *category_id in distinctNames) {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_id = %@", category_id];
            NSArray *category_group = [_aryClippedCategoryList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
            [result setObject:category_group forKey:category_id];

NSLog(@"123 - %@", result); 
NSLog(@"223 - %lu", (unsigned long)distinctNames.count);
```

In NSLog 123, result will look like:-

```
 17 =     (
                {
            "category_id" = 17;
            "category_name" = "Apparel & Accessories";
            "sub_category_id" = 17;
            "sub_category_name" = "Fashion jewelry";
        },
                {
            "category_id" = 17;
            "category_name" = "Apparel & Accessories";
            "sub_category_id" = 16;
            "sub_category_name" = Wholesale;
        }   
    );
    20 =     (
                {
            "category_id" = 20;
            "category_name" = "Beauty & Personal Care";
             "sub_category_id" = 288;
            "sub_category_name" = "Pedicure & medicure";
        },
                {
            "category_id" = 20;
            "category_name" = "Beauty & Personal Care";
            "sub_category_id" = 285;
            "sub_category_name" = "Fragrances and perfumes";
        }
);
```

In NSLog 223, result will look like:-

```
223 - 2
```

In this case, how can I select category_group as section value in CollectionView and show each group of items (category_id,category_name,sub_category_id,sub_category_name) in CollectionView cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- (**not recommended**)You should use NSMutableArray instead of NSMutableDictionary.

  structure is

  ```
  Array<Dictionary<Array *> *> *
  ```

  code is like this

  ```
  NSMutableArray *groups = [NSMutableArray new];
  <# your code #>
  [groups addObject:@{
      @"category_id": category_id,
      @"infos": category_group
  }];
  ```

  then

  ```
  NSString *groupID = groups[indexPath.section][@"category_id"]
  ```

  this is group value you need for sections.

  ```
  NSArray *infos = groups[indexPath.section][@"infos"];
  NSDictionary *info = infos[indexPath.item];
  ```

  this is object `dict` value for items
- (**recommended**) or transform your `data` to a `object`. (objects `NSMutableArray<Object *> *`)

  then use `groups.count` to get sections.

  ```
  groups[indexPath.section].categoryID
  ```

  this is group value you need for `sections`.

  ```
  group = groups[indexPath.section]
  object = group.infos[indexPath.item]
  ```

  this is object value for `items`

Comment: Hi @Frank, thanks for your detail explaination. But I stuck at `- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section { ` how can I pass in numberOfItemInSection if the section value is groups.count?

Comment: `group.infos.count`
that is what you need for items.
I just made some mistakes. srr.

Comment: `groups.count` is for `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSLog like this:

```
NSLog(@"123 - %@", result); 
NSLog(@"223 - %lu", (unsigned long)distinctNames.count);
```

You are explicitly asking it to be a String value and none equations will be calculated.

If you want to print results as Integer, you have to do it like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", 123 - result); 
NSLog(@"%lu", 223 - (unsigned long)distinctNames.count);
```

First parameter is String formatting, next arguments will be used to replace `%` in this String. So your calculations must be done on the right side.

To make it even more visible, best will be to create local variable with result before NSLog.

Comment: Hi @grzegorz, thanks for your reply. Actually my concern is how to set the object "category_group" as mentioned above to section. Currently I hit error in numberOfItemsInSection and numberOfSectionsInCollectionView as I have no idea how to assign value for it.